# Handling AES encryption using CTR mode (storing vi)

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I was trying to come up with AES encryption scheme for my project. Basically I want the user to crypt data using just a 32 byte key to decrypt a file of crypted data, since remembering and storing vi for every block seems very cumbersome. I know of many encryption programs that use just a key for encryption and nothing else. How do i go about this problem?

My current scheme looks something like this:

> Block:
> 16 bytes vi,
> up to 1 048 576 bytes of data (1MB)
>
> Encryption:
>
> 1. Input 32 byte key
> 2. First vi is randomly generated 16
>    bytes that get encrypted with AES ECB (initial key)
> 3. 1MB of data is encrypted using CTR (initial key, the block vi)
> 4. Any further block follows the same logic
>
> Decryption:
>
> 1. Input 32 byte key
> 2. Decrypt first 16 bytes using ECB
> 3. Decrypt the first block of data using CTR (initial key, the block vi)
> 4. Any further block follows the same logic

Is this good enough security wise? I think it should work since vi for every block is random, and since vi itself is encrypted using ECB it works pretty much like one time pad, correct?

Comment: Don't invent your own schemes and modes. The CTR mode IV should be prepended in the clear to the cipher stream, not encrypted. Your scheme actually leaks the first 16 bytes of plaintext because guess what is XORed the first block of plaintext? That's right, the ECB encryption of the IV.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you for answering! So to clarify, all i need to do is do the same encryption method as one in the original post but without encrypting the vi?